# Parallel Multiple DC/DC Regulators for Powering 100 LEDs: Load Sharing Techniques vs. Splitting the Load

Tags: led, dc-dc-converter, led-strip

Can I effectively power 100 LEDs with a total draw of 1.2A using 2 separate 1A DC/DC switching converters, each powering half of the LEDs, instead of implementing load-sharing techniques like load-sharing resistors or droop load sharing? I'm fairly new to this and trying to learn, so I apologize if this question seems basic. Any guidance on this approach and its feasibility would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The datasheet of one LED part number lists its RANGE of forward voltages. A blue one is probably 2.8V minimum to 3.6V maximum. Then what voltage will you feed parallel ones? If you feed them 2.8V then some will not light and if you feed then 3.6V then some of them will be VERY bright then will quickly burn out. The solution is to feed each one with its own current source (a series resistor).

Comment: Hi @Audioguru,
.
Thanks a lot for your comment on LED voltage variations. Your insight about different colours requiring different voltages was an eye-opener. I hadn't realized this before.

Your advice broadened my understanding. Your input is much appreciated.
Best regards,
Kyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

If you think of it, you are just using one supply to power 50 LEDs, and you have two of those sets.

Comment: I wanted to extend my gratitude for your prompt and informative response to my question!

I appreciate your willingness to share your expertise, especially considering that I'm still in the process of learning about these concepts. Your response has given me the confidence to proceed with my project in this manner.

Thank you once again for taking the time to assist me. Your guidance has been invaluable.